# Filters in Elasticsearch 1.7 and java client

Tags: elasticsearch, filter, elasticsearch-1.7.5

I'm using ES 1.7, and i'm experiencing some issues with filters.
each doc in our index has a language (PRL), Board of Appeal(BOA), and many other filter.
Our application is developed in JAVA and deployed in 5 environments. as an example we have TEST and INTG.
In both environments, a default search is working fine, the application gets responses from elasticsearch, but in INTG environment, it's not working with PRL and BOA and some other filters but it's working in TEST.
The mapping and the package developed in both TEST and INTG are the same.

Can you please provide me an other cause that can be happen?

Many thanks,
Mohammed ESSABRI

Comment: Have you checked the elastic search logs if there is any error?

Comment: Yes, but no exception is appearing!